# Login em site com requisição POST em python?

Tags: python, post, requisição

Gostaria de fazer login nesse site http://www.ciee.org.br/portal/LOGIN.ASP

onde sua form:

```
<form name="frmLogin" method="post" action="validalogin.asp" >                  
          <span>Login:</span>
          <span>
          <input title="Informe seu login (inclusive LETRAS e '*' quando houver)" name="usuario" type="text" size="20" maxlength="70" onFocus="limpa()">
          </span>
          <span>Senha:</span>
          <span>
          <input title="Informe a senha fornecida pelo CIEE" name="passwd" type="password" value="" size="15" maxlength="15"></span>
          <br/>
         <center><input type="button" value="ok" onClick="document.frmLogin.submit();" style="cursor:pointer;">
         </center>
  </form>
```

tentei o seguinte:

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.ciee.org.br/portal/LOGIN.ASP'
parametros = urllib.urlencode({'usuario':'usr', 'passwd': 'psw'})
html = urllib.urlopen(url, parametros).read()
print html
```

mas não deu certo, acho que é por causa do botão

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não ponha *nunca* dados reais de login  - prinicpaemtne senha, em nenhum recurso online - sempre substitua os valores que você tem por "*" ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Precisa ser usando urllib? Se não for uma necessidade, pode fazer via selenium.

Comment: Para quem tentou editar para remover as credenciais: o certo é sinalizar para a moderação. As credenciais continuam visíveis no histórico de edição se você apenas editar.

Comment: Assim como o @DenisCallau disse, se não tiver necessidade de usar urllib, tente fazer usando selenium, acho que fica mais fácil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o ideal seria através de uma API, geralmente esses serviços disponibilizam API's com procedimentos para acesso, o ideal seria verificar isso antes. Se não tiver disponivel, tente o selenium.

### [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Uma alternativa seria o [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), descrição do site (tradução e adaptação livre):

> O Selenium automatiza os navegadores. É isso aí! O que você faz com esse poder depende inteiramente de você. Principalmente, para automatizar aplicações web para fins de teste, mas certamente não está limitado a apenas isso. Tarefas chatas de administração baseadas na web podem (e devem!) ser automatizado também.

Exemplo de acesso ao facebook (é só adaptar para o seu caso):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Login/senha
user = "nome_user"
pwd = "senha"

# Inicializacao do driver Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Abrindo a pagina do facebook
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")

# Entrada do nome do usuário / email
elmnt = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elmnt.send_keys(user)

# Entrada da senha
elmnt = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elmnt.send_keys(pwd)

# Pressionando o botão de login
elmnt.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Fechando o driver
driver.close()
```